# What is the difference between Firebase/Auth and FirebaseUI/Auth?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

For Firebase iOS, if I want to do user authentication, is there any difference between these 3 choices?

- FirebaseUI
- FirebaseUI/Auth
- Firebase/Auth

And it would be great if someone can explain the pros and cons of using the "pre-built" FirebaseUI and the Firebase authentication SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see One thing in Docs Listed At - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

[image]
It provide full sign in flow to your app , All pods frameworks needed to sign in through app is provided by that

**--> A short Difference let me try to Explain with pod File**

-> If used `pod 'FirebaseUI'`

```
  Refer to Docs Page at - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui
```

And you will see

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'

pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
```

For login procedures like Facebook and google is being provided with pods using firebaseUi only

Whereas in pod `'Firebase/Auth'`

if you look to if we need to connect Facebook or gmail we explicitly use default Pods being provided with Social services as

[image]

**and** for Facebook

Second Again referring to main Doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Under `Firebase SDK Authentication` you can see what various integration we can use

[image]

**i.e You can sign in users to your Firebase app either by using FirebaseUI as a complete drop-in auth solution or by using the Firebase Authentication SDK to manually integrate one or several sign-in methods into your app**

Answer (score 5):

The Firebase/Auth pod is the [core SDK for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start).  You can't do authentication without it.  It provides no UI.

FirebaseUI is [UI components built on top of Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui) that handles login flows that make your app easier to write.  You can't use it without Firebase/Auth.